# How can I increase the size of the VirtualBox screen?

Tags: virtualbox

I setup VirtualBox, have Lubuntu 20.04 as guest OS but its screen size is miscroscopic. How can I change it?

[image]

Comment: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=91128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screen indicates the need to install Virtual Box Guest Extensions in the Ubuntu Machine.

This should augment video and allow the Ubuntu screen to fill the VBOX screen.

Here is a nice article to help you.

[Ubuntu Guest Extensions](https://www.itzgeek.com/post/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

> Prerequisites Install the build tools and kernel headers for the
> current kernel.
>
> COPY sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt install -y build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) Install
> Guest Additions After attaching VirtualBox guest additions ISO image,
> install it either using a terminal or graphical mode.
>
> Using Terminal On the VM window, go to Devices » Insert Guest
> Additions CD Image.
>
> Open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+T and mount the ISO image to /media
> directory.
>
> COPY sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media Execute the VirtualBox guest
> addition installer.
>
> COPY cd /media
>
> sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run Even before the installation gets
> complete, your system will get the full-screen view which confirms
> that the installation is successful.